# Incorrect status in test

Tags: spring, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying test my code, but I cannot run tests. I started writing my test of controllers.

My controller in test returns incorrect status. I don't know why. What did I do wrong? 
I get 200 (Ok), but I should get 201 (Created). It looks like the mocked controller, but I didn't do it anywhere.

My controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/auth")
class AuthenticationController(
        @Autowired private val userService: UserService,
        @Autowired private val tokenProvider: JwtTokenProvider,
        @Autowired private val authenticationManager: AuthenticationManager
) {
    @PostMapping("/registration")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    fun registerNewUser(@Valid @RequestBody request: RegisterAccountRequest): User {
        return userService.createUser(
                request.firstName,
                request.lastName,
                request.email,
                request.password
        )
    }
}
```

And my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@WebMvcTest(AuthenticationController::class)
@WebAppConfiguration
class AuthenticationControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var mockMvc: MockMvc

    @Autowired
    lateinit var objectMapper: ObjectMapper

    @Autowired
    lateinit var authController: AuthenticationController
    @Test
    fun whenUserIsValid_thenCreateNewAccount() {
        val firstName = "FirstName"
        val lastName = "LastName"
        val email = "Email"
        val password = "Password"

        val request = RegisterAccountRequest().apply {
            this.firstName = firstName
            this.lastName = lastName
            this.email = email
            this.password = password
        }

        given(authController.registerNewUser(request)).willReturn(User(firstName, lastName, email, password))

        val mock = mockMvc.perform(post("/registration")
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(request))
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isCreated)
                .andReturn()

        assertThat(mock.response.contentAsString).isNotEmpty()
    }
}
```

Comment: Try changing to: mockMvc.perform(post("/api/v1/auth/registration")

Comment: I found the problem. I started the debugger and I catch exception on this line: given(authController.registerNewUser(request)).willReturn(User(firstName, lastName, email, password)). It's java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException - `User cannot be returned by toString() toString() should return String`